# How to increase send buffer size of a SocketChannel?

Tags: java, bytebuffer, socketchannel

I've tried to increase the send buffer size of a SocketChannel. I want to send all the bytes in my ByteBuffer in only one write operation. This is my code:

```
channel = SocketChannel.open(address);
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(channelBytes);
channel.socket().setSendBufferSize(buf.remaining());
channel.write(buf);
```

Even if I call the method setSendBufferSize, the socket doesn't send more than 131071 bytes.
How can I do?

The receiver is this:

Constructor

```
uplink = ServerSocketChannel.open();
uplink.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(UPLINK_PORT));
uplink.socket().setReceiveBufferSize(2*1024*1024);
```

Run method

```
SocketChannel clientChannelUp = uplink.accept();
clientChannelUp.socket().setReceiveBufferSize(2*1024*1024);
clientChannelUp.socket().setSendBufferSize(2*1024*1024);
buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Short.MAX_VALUE*100);
clientChannelUp.read(buffer);
buffer.flip();
```

With the read and write loop my code is this:

transmitter

```
while(buf.hasRemaining()) {
    channel.write(buf);
}
```

receiver

```
int r = clientChannelUp.read(buffer);
while(r==131071) {
    r=clientChannelUp.read(buffer);
}
buffer.flip();
```

Comment: How this actually works in OS dependant.  You can call getSendBufferSize to see the actual size of the buffer.

Comment: If I call getSendBufferSize without set it first, the result is 8192. But the channel send 131071 bytes. I'm confuse

Comment: How do you know? With that code you can't possibly tell how much was sent.

Comment: When I call read(buffer) in the other thread I see (with the debug mode) that the position of the buffer is 131071.

Comment: Exactly. You measured the receiver and you're blaming the sender. The fact of the matter is that this code *is* sending all the data, but your socket *receive* buffer at the peer only holds 131071 bytes. In blocking mode, sending blocks until all data has been transferred to the send buffer.

Comment: To add up on @EJP comment, *transferred to the send buffer* **locally**, which does not mean it has been sent on the network (but then there is nothing more you can do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have posted blocks until all the data has been transferred into the socket send buffer, independently of the socket send buffer size. Your own experiments prove that. You didn't set it to 131071, left it at 8192, and yet 131071 bytes were still received.

What you mean is that the *peer* doesn't *receive* more than 131071 bytes.

That's because of the size of *its* socket *receive* buffer.

To set a socket receive buffer size larger than 64k it needs to be set before the socket is connected. In the case of a server, that means setting it in the `ServerSocket` or `ServerSocketChannel` before calling `accept()`.

However your basic objective isn't realizable. TCP is a byte stream protocol. It isn't obliged to deliver more than one byte at a time, or zero in non-blocking mode. If you want to receive *N* bytes, in general you have to loop.

Comment: Doesn't work. The receiver is a ServerSocketChannel. In the constructor I do this: uplink.socket().setReceiveBufferSize(2*1024*1024); but nothing

Comment: And what is the result of calling `getReceiveBufferSize()` on it immediately afterwards?

Comment: The result is 2097152

Comment: I tried to loop, but doesn't work. I don't know how. My system is in blocking mode

Comment: You don't know how to loop?

Comment: I don't know how to make it work properly. I tried to loop the writes and the reads on the other side, but with no results. In particular I think that the problem for me is the loop when I read

Comment: So post the current looping code. Edit it into your question.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, put this

```
clientChannelUp.socket().setReceiveBufferSize(2*1024*1024);
clientChannelUp.socket().setSendBufferSize(2*1024*1024);
```

in accept() and connected(), and it works.

Answer (score -3):

In the end I solved in this way:

transmitter

```
while(buf.hasRemaining()) {
    channel.write(buf);
}
```

receiver

```
int r = clientChannelUp.read(buffer);
while(r==131071) {
    r=clientChannelUp.read(buffer);
}
buffer.flip();
```

Comment: This solves nothing. The write loop spin-locks possibly forever, and the read loop is just complete nonsense. It throws away all data until the last partial read.

Comment: It works in my application. Why the read loop throws away all data until the last partial read? If it's incorrect tell me how I have to do.

Comment: Please people, don't do that... Did you at least try to increase your receive buffer size (`clientChannelUp.socket().setReceiveBufferSize(xxx)`), as @EJP pointed you too (several times...)? *Anything* is better that hard-coding an empirically-determined value.